# I want to do the animation on input text

Tags: html, css

I want to do the animation on input text, when I type on text input, have to show the text with animation effect.

Is it possible to do this kind of animation, if possible please suggest how to do.

I have attached sample ux

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. However this isn't a site for requesting code, you need to make an attempt yourself. For getting started, I would probably use JS to separate out each character as it's entered and wrapping it in an element, then using a CSS to apply an animation to each.

Answer (score 1):

**got it the solution**

```js
  function pinpad(cur){
    $(cur).parent().addClass('addclass');
  }
```

```css
.wrapper{
                width:320px;
                margin: 0px auto;
            }

        .ppWrapper {
        flex-direction: row;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: flex;
        place-content: center space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .addclass {
        font-family: 'Material Icons';
        content: "&#xE061;";
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 23px;
        line-height: 1;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        word-wrap: normal;
        direction: ltr;
        -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }
    .inputbox {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes flying {
        0% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
    
        2% {
          opacity: 0;
          -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        }
    
        5% {
          opacity: 1;
          -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    
        17% {
          opacity: 1;
          -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    
      }
    
      @-ms-keyframes flying {
        0% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
    
        2% {
          opacity: 0;
          -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
        }
    
        5% {
          opacity: 1;
          -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    
        17% {
          opacity: 1;
          -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    
      }
    
      @keyframes flying {
        0% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
    
        2% {
          opacity: 0;
          -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
          transform: translateY(-20px);
        }
    
        5% {
          opacity: 1;
          -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    
        17% {
          opacity: 1;
          -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    
      }
    .inputboxvalue{
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        font-size: 3em;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        border-radius: 0;
         color: transparent;
    }
    .addclass::before {
         font-family: "Material Icons";
         content: "\E061";
         position: absolute;
         margin: auto;
         top: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         left: 0px;
         text-align: center;
         color: black;
         width: 24px;
         height: 26px;
          -webkit-animation: flying 10s;
          -ms-animation: flying 10s;
          animation: flying 10s;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div  class="ppWrapper">
    <div  class="inputbox" >
      <input  class="inputboxvalue " type="password"  maxlength="1"  onkeydown="pinpad(this)">
    </div>
    <div  class="inputbox">
      <input  class="inputboxvalue "  type="password"  maxlength="1"  onkeydown="pinpad(this)">
    </div>
    <div  class="inputbox">
      <input  class="inputboxvalue "  type="password"  maxlength="1"  onkeydown="pinpad(this)">
    </div>
    <div  class="inputbox">
      <input  class="inputboxvalue " type="password"  maxlength="1"  onkeydown="pinpad(this)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you forgotten to attach your javascript?

Comment: #shadow, i edited my post hope now u can get clear picture on this,
using here material icons so please add this in below link

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">